# Stable nuclear isotopes

Tags: nuclear-physics, stability, binding-energy, isotopes

It appears that all stable nuclei may be seen to be composed of pairs of smaller, stable nuclei, e.g., the Li-7 nucleus seemingly is composed of H-3 and He-4, i.e., 1(3) + 2(4) -> 3(7). What if any is the significance of this?

It seems to me, if a regular lattice is assumed, that this means only certain nucleon moieties can form (conforming to that lattice), but not all such moieties can fit together to bond in the lattice, i.e., all stable nuclei must be composed of smaller, stable nuclei, but that not all stable nuclei can combine to former a larger stable nucleus (and of course there is an upper limit to how many nucleons can form a stable nucleus but this is due to something else).

Comment: Your statement "It appears that all stable nuclei may be seen to be composed of pairs of smaller, stable nuclei, e.g" is only true for very small nuclei
 if you speak of a lattice you think of nuclei like crystals, that is very wrong, there is no such thing as "lattice" in a nucleus.

Comment: Would you please give provide an example of a stable nucleus that cannot be written as a sum of a pair of stable nuclei? I am not a physicist, much less, a particle physicist, and could not find anything online in regard to "that all stable nuclei may be seen to be composed of pairs of smaller, stable nuclei... is only true for very small nuclei". Also, there is Nuclear Lattice Effective Field Theory, which is used to describe nuclear binding and structure.

Comment: The problem isn’t that you can’t combine two stable nuclei to make a third stable nuclei; the problem is that there are so many ways to do so that it doesn’t have any predictive power. See my updated answer for an example.

Comment: But H-3 (aka tritium) isn't stable, it has a half-life of 12.32 years.

Answer (score 2):

In most successful models of nuclei, the internal degrees of freedom are the nucleons: protons and neutrons. In the "shell model," nucleons can be assigned to orbitals with a particular energy and angular momentum, analogous to the electron orbitals that give the periodic table its structure. The shell model is quite successful at predicting nuclear ground states (a.k.a. "stable nuclei"), excited states, spins, decay rates, and so on.

It is occasionally useful to talk about "cluster nuclei," where you consider several of the nucleons within the nucleus to move together as a unit. A famous use of the cluster-nucleus model is Gamow's model of alpha decay as a tunneling process. You also find literature about cluster nuclei in analyses of $\rm (n,\alpha) $ interactions, where an incident neutron causes the nucleus to emit an alpha particle. In the case of $\rm (n,\alpha) $ on lithium-6 or boron-10, the alpha-particle part of the compound nucleus is comparable in size to the rest of it.

In stellar fusion the "alpha-particle nuclei," with $N=Z$ and $Z$ even, are important. Carbon exists because of the "triple-alpha process." Off the top of my head I can't think of a cluster-nucleus discussion where one of the clusters was *not* an alpha particle.

There is not a nucleon lattice; lattices have different symmetries than we see in nuclei. For literature about the emergence of a lattice structure in a few-body atomic system, you might look at "quantum dots." But I think that most people who make quantum dots are doing something different with them.

In a comment you ask for an example of a nucleus which cannot be written as a sum of a pair of stable nuclei. The difference between a chemical molecule like carbon monoxide and a cluster nucleus is that the chemical molecule has a *unique* decomposition into atoms.  Consider the alpha particle, helium-4, which can be decomposed into

- two protons and two neutrons
- a neutron bound to a helium-3 nucleus (two different ways)
- a proton bound to a tritium nucleus (two different ways)
- two deuterium nuclei bound together (two different ways)
- a diproton bound to a dineutron

Let’s look at the cluster $\rm^4He = n + {}^3He$ (“alpha equals neutron plus helion”).
When I wrote “two different ways,” I mean that you have two choices for which neutron is “free” versus being part of the cluster.
But you have more options than that.
When they are free, the neutron and the helion both have spin and parity $J^P = 1/2^+$, so you can produce the alpha particle’s $0^+$ by having the two constituents in an $s$-wave.
However, the neutron is unstable, but stabilized by the nucleus. We should also consider the possibility that the helion may have some excited state which is unstable on its own but contributes to the alpha particle’s ground state. There are a few different shell-model states for the helion which would have $J^P = 3/2^-$, which could still contribute to the alpha particle’s ground state by combining with the neutron in a $p$-wave.  A hypothetical $3/2^+$ helion could contribute both via $s$-wave and $d$-wave. I have a vague memory of reading a paper from the 1960s that went through this exercise for the alpha particle; the ground-state wavefunction had twenty or thirty different terms.

Imagine how chemistry would be different if nucleons could tunnel between the nuclei in a molecule, so that your carbon monoxide spent part of its time as a dinitrogen, and part of its time as a boron fluoride. That’s the trouble with a cluster-nucleus approach: since nothing holds the clusters apart, the combinatorics rapidly become impossible.

Comment: I am not sure how you answered my question, "It appears that all stable nuclei may be seen to be composed of pairs of smaller, stable nuclei... What if any is the significance of this? My subsidiary paragraph implies that if the above is true, it suggests, or at least is consistent with a lattice structure. My background is in quantum chemistry and chemical physics (and yes this has nothing to do with quantum dots).

Comment: ...Lattice models at the atomic-molecular level incorporate the electronic shell structure to model the properties of crystals. As a chemist, and using the analogy of of atomic shell structure to nuclear shell structure, at the nuclear level the nucleons are the atoms, and the nuclei are the molecules and the bonding between atoms is modeled as the interactions between the electrons and the nuclei, yet at the nuclear level, if I understand this, while the bonding within nucleons is modeled as the interactions between quarks, ...

Comment: the bonding between nucleons is modeled as interactions just between nucleons, and not as interactions between their constituent quarks. If at the atomic-molecular level, the interactions between atoms to form molecule were analogously (as it appears nucleon interactions are used to model nuclei) in terms of either ions, or neutral atoms interacting, it would produce poor results.

Comment: My answer is that people do usefully talk about cluster nuclei in limited circumstances, but not in a foundational way. You generally don’t talk about clusters of electrons within an atom’s electron cloud, for approximately the same reasons; the correspondence between electronic orbitals and the nuclear shell model is *very* close. For an explanation about why the relevant degrees of freedom are nucleons and (virtual) mesons rather than quarks, ask a follow-up question.

Comment: In response to my question, "It appears that all stable nuclei may be seen to be composed of pairs of smaller, stable nuclei... What if any is the significance of this?", you answered, that "all stable is only true for very small nuclei, and then in response to my following question to your above response, you answered, "The problem isn’t that you can’t combine two stable nuclei to make a third stable nuclei; the problem is that there are so many ways to do so that it doesn’t have any predictive power"...

Comment: You seem to be attributing someone else’s comment to me. I did not write the “very small nuclei” comment.

Comment: ... So, which is it? Also, your assertion, that "the difference between a chemical molecule like carbon monoxide and a cluster nucleus is that the chemical molecule has a unique decomposition into atoms". I think is not true: CO can be broken down into neutral atoms or ions in various states and charges in which spin, charge, etc... are preserved. As a chemist, it seems to me that nuclear binding analogously would be written in terms of wave-particle interactions between quarks rather than as either particle, or wave-particle interactions between nucleons.

Comment: Again, please show me a stable nucleus that cannot be composed of a pair of stable nuclei, i.e., that cannot be written as, [Z1](A1) + [Z2](A2) -> [Z1+Z2](A1+A2) where Z = #protons and A = Z + #neutrons.  The motivation for this observation, if it is true, is because it would be consistent with a lattice model for nuclear structure.

Comment: SORRY for confusing you with whomever, QM(?),,, !

Comment: This comment thread is getting unwieldy. Would you join me in [chat]?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128574/discussion-between-doc-and-rob).